# Calling other machines from the LinkedList if one is blocked or down

Tags: java, asynchronous, error-handling, http, guava

*This is a follow on to : [Simplifying asynchronous "executeAsync" method along with "onFailure" callback](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85347/simplifying-asynchronous-executeasync-method-along-with-onfailure-callback).*

I am using [`AsyncRestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) as my `HttpClient` to execute my URL and the server will return back a json string as the response. Customer will call this library by passing `DataKey` object which has `userId` in it.

- Given a `userId`, I will find out what are the machines that I can hit to get the data and then store those machines in a `LinkedList` so that I can execute them sequentially.
- After that I will check whether the first hostname is in block list or not. If it is not there in the block list, then I will make a URL with the first hostname in the list and execute it and if the response is successful then return back the response. But let's say if that first hostname is in the block list, then I will try to get the second hostname in the list and make the url and execute it so basically find the hostname which is not in block list before making the URL.
- Now, let's say if we selected first hostname which was not in the block list and executed the URL and somehow server was down or not responding, then I  will execute the second hostname in the list and keep doing this until you get a successful response. But make sure they were not in the block list as well so we need to follow above point.
- If all servers are down or in block list, then I can simply log and return the error that service is unavailable.

Below is my DataClient class which will be called by customer and they will pass `DataKey` object to `getData` method.

```
public class DataClient implements Client, DataFetcher {

    private final AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory());

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<DataResponse> getData(DataKey key) {
        final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture = SettableFuture.create();

        // given a userId, find all the hostnames 
        // so it can also have four hostname or one hostname or six hostname as well in the list
        LinkedList<String> listOfHostnames = getHostnamesInfo(key.getUserId());

        // any way to simplify this?
        boolean isFound = false;
        while (!listOfHostnames .isEmpty()) {
            String firstHostname = listOfHostnames .removeFirst();
            if (!ClientUtils.isEmpty(firstHostname) && !ShardMapping.isBlockHost(firstHostname)) {
                executeForServers(responseFuture, key, firstHostname, listOfHostnames );
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // all the servers were in block list
        if (!isFound) {
            responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
                    DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
        }

        return responseFuture;
    }

    @Override
    public void executeForServers(SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, DataKey key, String hostname,
            LinkedList<String> restHostnames) {

        // should I add the logic here?

        ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>> callback = new RetryCallback(this, responseFuture,
                hostname, restHostnames, key);
        restTemplate.exchange(generateURL(hostname, key), HttpMethod.GET, key.getEntity(),
                String.class).addCallback(callback);
    }
}
```

Below is my interface for `DataFetcher`:

```
public interface DataFetcher {
    void executeForServers(SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, DataKey key, String hostname,
            LinkedList<String> restHostnames);
}
```

Below is my `RetryCallback` class:

```
public class RetryCallback implements ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>> {
    private final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture;
    private final LinkedList<String> restHostnames;
    private final String hostname;
    private final DataKey key;
    private final DataFetcher dataFetcher;

    private RetryCallback(final DataFetcher dataFetcher, final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture,
            final String hostname, final LinkedList<String> restHostnames, final DataKey key) {
        this.dataFetcher = checkNotNull(dataFetcher);
        this.responseFuture = checkNotNull(responseFuture);
        this.hostname = checkNotNull(hostname);
        this.restHostnames = checkNotNull(restHostnames);
        this.key = checkNotNull(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
         responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(result.getBody(), DataErrorEnum.OK,
                DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS));
    }

    // any way to simplify this?
    // recursively calling executeForServers method
    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Throwable ex) {
        if (ex instanceof SocketException) {
            // if it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down so adding it into block list
            ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
            while (!restHostnames.isEmpty()) {
                String nextHostname = restHostnames.removeFirst();
                if (!ClientUtils.isEmpty(nextHostname) && !ShardMapping.isBlockHost(nextHostname)) {  // check to see whether hostname is blocked or not
                    dataFetcher.executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextHostname, restHostnames);
                    return;
                }
            }               
            // either  all the servers are down or all the servers were in block list
            if (ClientUtils.isEmpty(restHostnames)) {
                responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
                        DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
            }
        } else { // this is for 4xx (HttpClientErrorException) and 5xx (HttpServerErrorException) error coming from server side
            HttpStatusCodeException httpException = (HttpStatusCodeException) ex;
            DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.getErrorEnumByException(httpException);
            responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(httpException.getResponseBodyAsString(), error,
                    DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
        }
        // is there any other error I should look into?
    }
}
```

My block list keeps getting updated from another background thread every 1 minute. If any server is down and not responding, then I need to block that server by using this -

```
ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
```

And to check whether any server is in block list or not, I use this -

```
ShardMapping.isBlockHost(hostname);
```

I have my above code working fine so I am opting for code review to see whether we can simplify my above four points or not.

- As of now, I am doing same check at two places, one in `getData()` method and other in `onFailure()` method as well so wanted  to see whether is there any room for improvement or not.
- Also, is there any other error should I handle in my `onFailure` command? As of now, it only checks for `HttpClientErrorException`, `HttpServerErrorException` and `SocketException`.

Comment: To me it sounds terribly complicated. No time to try a real review or a solution, but what I'd do: 1. trivial synchronous solution looping through the hosts, skipping the blocked ones, waiting for the others, trying next on failure, otherwise returning. 2. wrap it all in a Future. +++ This may be completely wrong, but I can't see any reason against it in your question.

Comment: @maaartinus I am using AsyncRestTemplate bcoz of it's NIO based connections as this library will be used under very heavy load. And I need to provide both sync and async  methods as of now I am working on async method to make it work fine. Also, AsyncRestTemplate will return back ListenableFuture so we can do lot of things with that so that's why I am  going with this solution.

Comment: Lacking corresponding experience, I can't tell if it makes any sense, but there must be a simpler way. To remove the duplication you could move all the logic in the callback and call its `onFailure` (initially, there's no failure, but the situation is similar: the remaining hosts are to be tried).

Comment: @maaartinus This is what I am confuse how should I do it. I tried to come up with atleast two solution and both were code duplication so that's why I came here to see if there is any better way.

Comment: You can probably move quite some functionality into `listOfHostnames` (Make it to an `Iterator<String>` returning a next non-blocked host? Make it return a `Future`?). This asynchronicity drives me crazy,

Comment: I am closing this post because I don't believe the code works. The loop `for (String hostname : listOfHostnames)` modifies `listOfHostnames` inside it, which will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and additionally, the code has variables which are not declared anywhere (`hostnames`). The code can't compile.

Comment: @rolfl It doesn't have to throw, it may be a homegrown `List` or maybe there's such a thing in j.u.concurrent. `hostnames` is surely `listOfHostnames` (code copied, improved, and the partially updated here?). However, both iterating and removing the first element makes no sense to me! It looks like an interesting problem, so let's hope the OP fixes it soon.

Comment: @rolf I made a mistake while renaming the variables and now it is corrected. I should have noticed this earlier and I apologize for this. I am not sure about `ConcurrentModificationException` but I do see it works fine when I run it locally. May be there is a bug which you have caught it but I haven't got this exception so far at all.

Comment: @david You don't get the exception in the first branch because of the `break`: You modify the list but you don't iterate further, so it's fine. But whenever the very first element is blocked, you remove it and call `iterator.next()` which will throw. And even if not... what should it do??? You iterate to the next element and also remove the first one. It makes no sense. Replace the for-each loop by `while (!listOfHostnames.isEmpty())` and always access the first element (after the failed one was removed).

Comment: @maaartinus Let's say if I have two elements in the list, and if first hostname is blocked, then try with second hostname, and if that is also blocked, then log an error and return that service is unavailable. Also, let's say if we have only one hostname in the list, then if that one hostname is blocked, then we will log an error and return service unavailable error. I didn't see, I am using `iterator.next()` anywhere or does it get called internally?

Comment: The for-each loop is just an iterator loop. You get the first element from `next()`, modify the list, try to get the second via `next()`, and it blows. Or does it?

Comment: I just ran a quick test with only one element in the LinkedList which was blocked and it didn't throw any exception at all. It was also able to remove that element successfully from the same list.

Comment: IIUYC these were the first two steps from my above description and the third one throws.

Comment: @maaartinus how about now? I updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Name of `getHostnamesInfo` is misleading a little bit. It returns to `listOfHostnames`, so calling it `getHostnames` or `getHostnamesForUser` would be less confusing.
2. First, to DRY the code, I'd try to extract out some hostname list handling logic to a separate class:

   ```
    public class Hosts {

        private final LinkedList<String> hostsnames = newLinkedList();

        public Hosts(final List<String> hosts) {
            checkNotNull(hosts, "hosts cannot be null");
            this.hostsnames.addAll(hosts);
        }

        public Optional<String> getNextAvailableHostname() {
            while (!hostsnames.isEmpty()) {
                String firstHostname = hostsnames.removeFirst();
                if (!ClientUtils.isEmpty(firstHostname) && !ShardMapping.isBlockHost(firstHostname)) {
                    return Optional.of(firstHostname);
                }
            }
            return Optional.absent();
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return hostsnames.isEmpty();
        }
    }
   ```

It makes `getData` simpler:

```
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<DataResponse> getData(final DataKey key) {
        // given a userId, find all the hostnames
        // so it can also have four hostname or one hostname or six hostname as
        // well in the list
        final LinkedList<String> hostnames = getHostnames(key.getUserId());
        final Hosts hosts = new Hosts(hostnames);
        final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = hosts.getNextAvailableHostname();
        if (!nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
            final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture = SettableFuture.create();
            responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
            return responseFuture;
        }
        checkState(nextAvailableHost.isPresent());

        final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture = SettableFuture.create();
        executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextAvailableHost.get(), hosts);

        return responseFuture;
    }
```

and improves a little bit the `RetryCallback.onFailure` too:

```
    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Throwable ex) {
        if (ex instanceof SocketException) {
            // if it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down so adding it into block list
            ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
            
            final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = hosts.getNextAvailableHostname();
            if (nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
                dataFetcher.executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextAvailableHost.get(), hosts);
                return;
            }

            // either  all the servers are down or all the servers were in block list
            if (hosts.isEmpty()) {
                responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
            }
        } else { // this is for 4xx (HttpClientErrorException) and 5xx (HttpServerErrorException) error coming from server side
            HttpStatusCodeException httpException = (HttpStatusCodeException) ex;
            DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.getErrorEnumByException(httpException);
            responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(httpException.getResponseBodyAsString(), error,
                    DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
        }
        // is there any other error I should look into?
    }
```

1. You might notice some other duplication here, especially if you invert the condition in `getData`:

   ```
    final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture = SettableFuture.create();

    final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = hosts.getNextAvailableHostname();
    if (nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
        executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextAvailableHost.get(), hosts);
    } else {
        responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
    }

    return responseFuture;
   ```

I have created a *temporary* `execute` method for it in the `Hosts` class:

```
    public void execute(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final DataKey key, final DataFetcher dataFetcher) {
        final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = getNextAvailableHostname();
        if (nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
            dataFetcher.executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextAvailableHost.get(), this);
            return;
        }

        responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
    }
```

It probably has a bad name and probably it should not be in the `Hosts` class but it's enough in this internal step.

Now `getData` looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<DataResponse> getData(final DataKey key) {
        final LinkedList<String> hostnames = getHostnames(key.getUserId());
        final Hosts hosts = new Hosts(hostnames);
        final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture = SettableFuture.create();
        hosts.execute(responseFuture, key, this);
        return responseFuture;
    }
```

And `onFailure`:

```
    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Throwable ex) {
        if (ex instanceof SocketException) {
            // if it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down so adding it into block list
            ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
            hosts.execute(responseFuture, key, dataFetcher);
        } else { // this is for 4xx (HttpClientErrorException) and 5xx (HttpServerErrorException) error coming from server side
            HttpStatusCodeException httpException = (HttpStatusCodeException) ex;
            DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.getErrorEnumByException(httpException);
            responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(httpException.getResponseBodyAsString(), error,
                    DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
        }
    }
```

1. I don't feel that `Hosts` class fulfills the single responsibility principle. It handles hostnames well but the `execute` method seems another responsibility. Furthermore, it uses only the public API of `Hosts` which does not suggest high cohesion. So I moved this method to a new class:

   ```
    public class Retryer {

        public void execute(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final DataKey key,
                final DataFetcher dataFetcher, final Hosts hosts) {
            final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = hosts.getNextAvailableHostname();
            if (nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
                dataFetcher.executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextAvailableHost.get(), hosts);
                return;
            }

            responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
        }
    }
   ```

Usage in `onFailure`:

```
    new Retryer().execute(responseFuture, key, dataFetcher, hosts);
```

and in `getData`:

```
    new Retryer().execute(responseFuture, key, this, hosts);
```

Note that `isEmpty` in `Hosts` is not used, you could remove it. Furthermore, the `Retryer` name does not looks good, it smells for me.

1. Another duplication is in this line:

> ```
> responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(httpException.getResponseBodyAsString(), error,
>             DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
> ```

and this one:

> ```
> responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(null, DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
> ```

I moved these calls also to the `Retryer` class:

```
    public void execute(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final DataKey key,
            final DataFetcher dataFetcher, final Hosts hosts) {
        final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = hosts.getNextAvailableHostname();
        if (nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
            dataFetcher.executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextAvailableHost.get(), hosts);
            return;
        }

        setServiceUnavailable(responseFuture);
    }

    private void setServiceUnavailable(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture) {
        final String errorMessage = null;
        final DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
        setErrorReponse(responseFuture, errorMessage, error);
    }

    public void setErrorReponse(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final String errorMessage,
            final DataErrorEnum error) {
        final DataResponse dataResponse = new DataResponse(errorMessage, error, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
        responseFuture.set(dataResponse);
    }
```

1. I would consider creating a new constructor in the `DataResponse` which omits the `errorMessage` parameter so passing `null` does not clutter the code. (When I see a null parameter I always wonder which parameter is it. Unfortunately I have to check the implementation to figure it out.)
2. Another thing is that `errorMessage` can be `null`. Setting it to an empty string might save you from a few `NullPointerException`s later (if that's possible and sane).
3. Let's go back to the ugly `Retryer`. Currently it's the only one caller of `executeForServers`. Additionally, I have a feeling that I would prefer to call it `DataFetcherExecutor` or `DataFetcher` which is even better. Now, I changed `DataFetcher` from interface to class and moved both `Retryer.execute` and `DataClient.executeForServers` into it (along with their dependencies). When I've finished I got this:

   ```
    public class DataFetcher {

        private final AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(
                new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory());

        public void execute(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final DataKey key, final Hosts hosts) {
            final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = hosts.getNextAvailableHostname();
            if (nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
                executeForServers(responseFuture, key, nextAvailableHost.get(), hosts);
                return;
            }

            setServiceUnavailable(responseFuture);
        }

        public void executeForServers(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final DataKey key,
                final String hostname, final Hosts hosts) {
            final ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>> callback = new RetryCallback(this, responseFuture,
                    hostname, key, hosts);
            restTemplate.exchange(generateURL(hostname, key), HttpMethod.GET, key.getEntity(), String.class).addCallback(
                    callback);
        }

        private void setServiceUnavailable(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture) {
            final String errorMessage = null;
            final DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
            setErrorReponse(responseFuture, errorMessage, error);
        }

        public void setErrorReponse(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final String errorMessage,
                final DataErrorEnum error) {
            final DataResponse dataResponse = new DataResponse(errorMessage, error, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
            responseFuture.set(dataResponse);
        }

        ... // generateURL is here

    }
   ```

`Retryer` is empty, it can be removed now. `DataClient` also a lot simpler, it does not implement `DataFetcher` any more and it contains only some simple wiring logic:

```
    public class DataClient implements Client {

        @Override
        public ListenableFuture<DataResponse> getData(final DataKey key) {
            final LinkedList<String> hostnames = getHostnames(key.getUserId());
            final Hosts hosts = new Hosts(hostnames);
            final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture = SettableFuture.create();
            final DataFetcher dataFetcher = new DataFetcher();
            dataFetcher.execute(responseFuture, key, hosts);
            return responseFuture;
        }

        ... // getHostnames is here
    }
```

And `RetryCallback`:

```
    public class RetryCallback implements ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>> {
        private final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture;
        private final String hostname;
        private final DataKey key;
        private final DataFetcher dataFetcher;
        private final Hosts hosts;

        public RetryCallback(final DataFetcher dataFetcher, final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture,
                final String hostname, final DataKey key, final Hosts hosts) {
            this.dataFetcher = checkNotNull(dataFetcher);
            this.responseFuture = checkNotNull(responseFuture);
            this.hostname = checkNotNull(hostname);
            this.key = checkNotNull(key);
            this.hosts = checkNotNull(hosts);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
             responseFuture.set(new DataResponse(result.getBody(), DataErrorEnum.OK,
                    DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Throwable ex) {
            if (ex instanceof SocketException) {
                // if it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down so adding it into block list
                ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
                dataFetcher.execute(responseFuture, key, hosts);
            } else { // this is for 4xx (HttpClientErrorException) and 5xx (HttpServerErrorException) error coming from server side
                HttpStatusCodeException httpException = (HttpStatusCodeException) ex;
                DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.getErrorEnumByException(httpException);
                final String errorMessage = httpException.getResponseBodyAsString();
                dataFetcher.setErrorReponse(responseFuture, errorMessage, error);
            }
        }
    }
```

For me it seems quite good and simple, but do not stop yet.

1. Let's try to move body of `onSuccess` to `DataFetcher` as well. `DataFetches` contains some similar code already.

   ```
    public void setSuccessResponse(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final String message) {
        final DataResponse dataResponse = new DataResponse(message, DataErrorEnum.OK, DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
        responseFuture.set(dataResponse);
    }
   ```

Usage in `RetryCallback`:

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
        final String message = result.getBody();
        dataFetcher.setSuccessResponse(responseFuture, message);
    }
```

1. Notice in `RetryCallback` that `dataFetcher` is the only one object which uses the `responseFuture` reference of `RetryCallback`. It might be in the `DataFetcher` class and probably `RetryCallback` don't have to know anything about `responseFuture`, it should be an internal detail of `DataFetcher`. Let's try that and the same with the `hosts` and `key` fields too.

`DataFetcher` with the new fields and constructor parameters:

```
    public class DataFetcher {

        private final AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(
                new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory());

        private final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture;
        private final DataKey key;
        private final Hosts hosts;

        public DataFetcher(final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture, final DataKey key, final Hosts hosts) {
            this.responseFuture = checkNotNull(responseFuture);
            this.key = checkNotNull(key);
            this.hosts = checkNotNull(hosts);
        }

        public void tryNextHost() {
            final Optional<String> nextAvailableHost = hosts.getNextAvailableHostname();
            if (nextAvailableHost.isPresent()) {
                doExchange(nextAvailableHost.get());
                return;
            }

            setServiceUnavailable();
        }

        private void doExchange(final String hostname) {
            final ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>> callback = new RetryCallback(this, hostname);
            final URI url = generateURL(hostname, key);
            restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, key.getEntity(), String.class).addCallback(
                    callback);
        }

        private void setServiceUnavailable() {
            final String errorMessage = null;
            final DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
            setErrorReponse(errorMessage, error);
        }

        public void setErrorReponse(final String errorMessage, final DataErrorEnum error) {
            final DataResponse dataResponse = new DataResponse(errorMessage, error, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
            responseFuture.set(dataResponse);
        }

        public void setSuccessResponse(final String message) {
            final DataResponse dataResponse = new DataResponse(message, DataErrorEnum.OK, DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
            responseFuture.set(dataResponse);
        }
        
        ...
    }
```

Note the removed `responseFuture` parameters of almost every method. I've also renamed a few methods.

Now, here is `RetryCallback`:

```
    public class RetryCallback implements ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>> {
        private final String hostname;
        private final DataFetcher dataFetcher;

        public RetryCallback(final DataFetcher dataFetcher, final String hostname) {
            this.dataFetcher = checkNotNull(dataFetcher);
            this.hostname = checkNotNull(hostname);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final ResponseEntity<String> result) {
            final String message = result.getBody();
            dataFetcher.setSuccessResponse(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Throwable ex) {
            if (ex instanceof SocketException) {
                // if it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down so
                // adding it into block list
                ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
                dataFetcher.tryNextHost();
            } else { // this is for 4xx (HttpClientErrorException) and 5xx
                // (HttpServerErrorException) error coming from server side
                final HttpStatusCodeException httpException = (HttpStatusCodeException) ex;
                final DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.getErrorEnumByException(httpException);
                final String errorMessage = httpException.getResponseBodyAsString();
                dataFetcher.setErrorReponse(errorMessage, error);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is so much simpler now.

Finally, `DataClient`:

```
    public class DataClient implements Client {

        @Override
        public ListenableFuture<DataResponse> getData(final DataKey key) {
            final LinkedList<String> hostnames = getHostnames(key.getUserId());
            final Hosts hosts = new Hosts(hostnames);
            final SettableFuture<DataResponse> responseFuture = SettableFuture.create();
            final DataFetcher dataFetcher = new DataFetcher(responseFuture, key, hosts);
            dataFetcher.tryNextHost();
            return responseFuture;
        }

        ...
    }
```

1. It seems quite good but you should test it: write unit tests for the refactored classes. If it's easy it might sign that it's a good design. If it's hard - that means that the code definitely needs further improvements. ([Killing the Helper class, part two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nickmalik/killing-the-helper-class-part-two) will help you.)

1. Finally, I would improve `RetryCallback` a little:

   ```
    if (ex instanceof SocketException) {
        // if it comes here, then it means some of the servers are down so
        // adding it into block list
        ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
        dataFetcher.tryNextHost();
    } else {
        ...
    }
   ```

You could extract out an explanatory variable:

```
    final boolean serverDown = ex instanceof SocketException;
    if (serverDown) {
        ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
        dataFetcher.tryNextHost();
    } else {
```

It eliminates the comment. See: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods, Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*; *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Once again pretty detailed code review. Thanks for your time. Really appreciated. I have started to go through all your points step by step.